# SMS send control character ctrl z + ESC

Tags: sms

My DTU want <ctrl-Z/ESC>
How do I sent that ? Using windows 10

So in the text im sending it wants your msg followed by    <ctrl-Z/ESC>
In the past I found a character that represented <ctrl-Z/ESC>. I would past after the text and that worked

AT+CMGS="13012832788"(TEXT MODE)(AT+CSCS=”IRA”)

> ABCD<ctrl-Z/ESC>
> +CMGS: 46
> OK

I think it was a printer code but i cant remember
I copied the character but cant find it